# Excel VBA : search an array referring to a structure

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a type line below and created one dimensional array out of it:

```
Public Type file_sizes
    fName As String
    fsize As Integer
End Type
    
Global file_array(1000) As file_sizes
```

I have an excel which contains some contract numbers and filenames.

I want to build another array with a structure like below:

```
Public Type ctr_file_sizes
    ctr_id As String
    fName As String
    fsize As Integer
End Type
```

My task is to look into the array `file_array` and find out for a given file name what is the value in field `fsize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I see why `ctr_file_sizes` exists. It seems the info you want is in all in the `file_sizes` type.

I'd suggest using a dictionary

```
Option Explicit

Dim files As New Dictionary

Sub populateFiles()
    
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To 1000   'iterate over your files however you please
        files.Add "file name", 3456
    Next
    
    
    'then to get a specific file's size
    Dim sizeYouWant As Long
    sizeYouWant = files("file name")
    
End Sub
```

You'll need a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

[image]

Comment: And even if he does need to have that type he set up with the id, name and size, he can always make dict of those with fName as the key.

Comment: haha, yes correct, and user\d+ doesn't tell me a lot.  English just lacks a non-gendered pronoun better than 'it', and 'it' didn't seem appropriate.  So you just have to pick one.  Next time I'll pick she, just to even it all out.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do something like that?

```
Option Explicit

Public Type file_sizes
    fName As String
    fsize As Integer
End Type
    
Public Type ctr_file_sizes
    ctr_id As String
    fName As String
    fsize As Integer
End Type

Global file_array(1000) As file_sizes

Sub Testit()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrCtr() As ctr_file_sizes

    ' some Testdata
    file_array(0).fName = "Given file Name"
    file_array(0).fsize = 1024
    
    file_array(1).fName = "Other file Name"
    file_array(1).fsize = 1048

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "Given file Name"
    Dim hit As Long
    For i = LBound(file_array) To UBound(file_array)
        If file_array(i).fName = fileName Then
            ReDim Preserve arrCtr(hit)
            arrCtr(hit).fName = file_array(i).fName
            arrCtr(hit).fsize = file_array(i).fsize
            arrCtr(hit).ctr_id = i  ' or whatever ctr_id is good for
            hit = hit + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```